# Can the Spotify App framework cope with playing two things at once?

Tags: spotify

I'm interested in fiddling with a Spotify app to see whether it's possible to produce a radio type experience, which involves playing at least two things at once.

Is this possible within the Spotify API - or is it only capable of controlling one play control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope! Only one thing can be playing at once.